# How to automatically align comments in different pieces of code?

Tags: emacs, comments, alignment, text-formatting

I have to do a very specific task to re-do over and over again and would like to have it put permanently in my `.emacs` file. But I am not versed enough in emacs-lisp to manage it:

- Keystroke-1, say <kbd>F8</kbd>

  - remember the current cursors' column position in, say, `xtab`
- Keystroke-2, say <kbd>F9</kbd> while cursor is in some other line:
- find leftmost string `//` in current line, if none is there, beep and stop
- insert as many spaces so the `//` gets to previously remembered column `xtab`, or do nothing if cursor is already beyond `xtab`
- search-forward for next `//` and place the cursor on it

I managed to assign it to a temporary keyboard macro, but have to re-record it for every changing `xtab` value.

The ultimate goal is that I want to align the comments in different pieces of code easily, from

```c
int main() {     // the enty function
    int x = 100; // my new variable
    for(int i=1; i<2012; ++i) { // loop a lot
        x -= i;
    } 
} // end of all things
```

to

```c
int main() {                    // the entry function
    int x = 100;                // my new variable
    for(int i=1; i<2012; ++i) { // loop a lot
        x -= i;
    } 
}                               // end of all things
```

Any idea how I can automate this? What do I have to put in my `.emacs`-file to archive this -- or similar?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As tungd said, `align-regexp` is good for this sort of thing.

```el
(defun my-align-comments (beginning end)
  "Align instances of // within marked region."
  (interactive "*r")
  (let (indent-tabs-mode align-to-tab-stop)
    (align-regexp beginning end "\\(\\s-*\\)//")))
```

Which is like the interactive call:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `align-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `//` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Or for a more language-agnostic version:

```el
(defun my-align-comments (beginning end)
  "Align comments within marked region."
  (interactive "*r")
  (let (indent-tabs-mode align-to-tab-stop)
    (align-regexp beginning end (concat "\\(\\s-*\\)"
                                        (regexp-quote comment-start)))))
```

Comment: I never thought that emacs has a command already for that. Works like a treat!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code:

```el
(defvar c-current-comment-col 30)
(defun c-set-comment-col ()
  (interactive)
  (setq c-current-comment-col (current-column)))
(defun c-comment-to-col ()
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line)
    (when (re-search-forward "//" (line-end-position) t)
      (backward-char 2)
      (let ((delta (- c-current-comment-col
                      (current-column))))
        (if (plusp delta)
            (insert (make-string delta ? ))
          (if (looking-back
               (format "\\( \\{%d\\}\\)" (- delta)))
              (delete-region
               (match-beginning 1)
               (match-end 1))
            (message
             "I'm sorry Dave, I afraid can't do that.")))))
    (next-line 1))
(global-set-key [C-f6] 'c-set-comment-col)
(global-set-key [f6] 'c-comment-to-col)
```

I've added a `next-line` call to the end. Now you can do
<kbd>C-f6 f3 f6 M-0 f4</kbd> to align until end of buffer.

Comment: Great. Actually, I am not in c++-mode, it's text with source code sprinkled in it (fundamental, flyspell), so I used `(global-set-key [S-f6] 'c-set-comment-col)` instead. Also, I added searching for the `//` in the current line before setting `c-current-comment-col` for convenience. But I can't figure out how to search for the next `//` at the end of `c-comment-to-col`... so I can just repeat pressing the macro key without searching manually.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but to achieve the desired goal you can just mark the region and use `align-regexp`.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `align` is very powerful and will automatically handle the particular example given.

However, it will also align variable declarations, which may be more than you want. In that case, you would have to customize `align-region-separate` or use the `align-regexp` answer.